# Highstock: placing a legend between the chart and navigator

Tags: highcharts

Highstock comes with a mini-chart called the navigator that allows panning and zooming of the main chart. I'd like to add a legend. When I enable the legend, it appears under the navigator. Can I sandwich the legend between the chart and the navigator, where the x axis label would go?

I tried this: setting a wide margin on the navigator, floating the legend, and positioning the legend in the margin space using a negative y position.

```
    legend: {
        enabled: true,         
        floating: true,
        y: -65
    },
    navigator: {
        margin: 50
    }
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/v4vva3wL/**

The problem with this solution: the legend isn't part of the layout, so if the chart container width shrinks (on mobile phones) the margin area is not tall enough to accommodate the legend.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Comment: Let's test the responsive version of your chart http://jsfiddle.net/2wqupj2e/1/. I tested that in each width and always seems to working fine. Could you elaborate what is wrong?

Comment: @SebastianBochan thanks for pointing out my example doesn't show the problem. I've revised my example and added a screenshot to clearly show the problem.

Comment: It seem fixed with latest version?